# Botões invisíveis no emulador mas visíveis na pré-visualização

Tags: android

Por que os botões que crio no xml não aparecem no avd? NO layout eles aparecem com uma cor cinza, porém quando boto para rodar no emulador eles simplesmente estão invisíveis. Caso eu coloque algum text no botão, o texto aparece, mas o botão não. Estou seguindo o tutorial para criação deste jogo e não fiz nada de diferente, porém o meu está assim.

[image: Android Studio mostrando uma prévia do layout criado, no qual aparece uma grade de botões cinzas sem nenhum texto dentro deles]

[image: Emulador de Android executando a aplicação. A tela está vazia, como se os botões estivessem invisíveis]

meu arquivo xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:tag="quadrado1"
            android:onClick="clickQuadrado" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:tag="quadrado2"
            android:onClick="clickQuadrado" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:tag="quadrado3"
            android:onClick="clickQuadrado" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:tag="quadrado4"
            android:onClick="clickQuadrado" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:tag="quadrado5"
            android:onClick="clickQuadrado" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:tag="quadrado6"
            android:onClick="clickQuadrado" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:tag="quadrado7"
            android:onClick="clickQuadrado" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:tag="quadrado8"
            android:onClick="clickQuadrado" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:tag="quadrado9"
            android:onClick="clickQuadrado" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: É interessante também você mostrar o código que está em `main.xml`

Comment: Gustavo, a menos que você tenha outras definições em sua `Activity` para estes botões, tudo que você faz é só definir dimensões e ação do clique praticamente. Você precisa de um background, um texto ou algo parecido. Para isso você precisa das propriedades `android:background` ou `android:text`, por exemplo. Para contextualizar, você tem o link deste tutorial que está seguindo?

Comment: Ok obrigado. Estou seguindo o tutorial do canal eXcript https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsJkaAnd9uY. Outra dúvida, quando dou uma margin no primeiro Linear Layout (mais externo), as alterações são aplicadas somente no preview do  XML, no emulador fica o mesmo, a não ser se aplico as alterações a partir do segundo Linear layout, daí funciona certinho. Só que aí custarias mais linhas... Obrigado

Comment: Esqueci de comentar que no tutorial que citei no qual estou seguindo, ele não aplica nenhum background nos buttons, o que pensei que seria algum erro de configuração no meu.

Comment: Gustavo, dá uma olhada se não é o tema que vc está utilizando que está tornando o botão invisível (por terem a mesma cor). O que acontece quando vc pressiona o local onde o botão devia estar? Ele responde?

Comment: Boa Tarde @Gustavo, testei seu xml e está aparecendo todos os botões. Acredito que seja algo que você esteja fazendo na sua classe. Qualquer duvida estou a disposição para ajuda-lo.

Comment: Gustavo, testei aqui e está funcionando bem. Mas de qualquer forma, se não aparece ai, você pode tentar alterar a cor dos botões. Clicando no botão>indo em properties (canto direito da tela)>background>color.. 
Assim você pode definir uma cor diferente. Se os botões estiverem da mesma cor do tema, isso já resolvera. Verifica também se na tua classe java não tem nenhum método setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Pois se tiver, ele pode ser o motivo de não aparecerem..

Answer (score 2):

Testei no **Android Studio** seu **xml**, ele mostra o botão normalmente na minha máquina virtual.

Tente este escopo para cada botão:

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/buttonX"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
                android:onClick="clickQuadrado"/>
```